# How to convert PowerShell object property values into an HTML table fragment?

Tags: powershell, html-table, type-conversion

I want to use PS to create an HTML report with multiple tables, similar to what is summarized [here](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/making-html-reports-powershell) quite succinctly.  I have tried many different ways, however I can't seem to get the values to populate the HTML table fragments correctly.

What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

To use one small table as an example, let's say I want to list the installed versions of .NET on a system.

I can populate an array of objects using:

```
$netver = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse |
Get-ItemProperty -name Version,Release -EA 0 |
Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |
Select PSChildName, Version, Release |ft;
```

... and the values are there correctly (checking with just `$netver`).

According to the page referenced, as well as other pages referencing the same, I should just need to do something like the following:

```
$netverhtml = $netver | ConvertTo-Html -AS Table -Fragment -Property * | out-string;
```

...and the fragment should be ready to include when building the final html page, with something similar to this...

```
ConvertTo-HTML -body "$netverhtml" |   Out-File $logfile
```

... however even before I get there, the fragment (`$netverhtml`)  doesn't contain the data (similar to what is in `$netver`), let alone when the html page is finally constructed.

Unless I use a string, I keep ending up with formatting data in the HTML table structure (end result below).

```
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd</th><th>pageHeaderEntry</th><th>pageFooterEntry</th><th>autosizeInfo</t
h><th>shapeInfo</th><th>groupingEntry</th></tr>
<tr><td>033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Form
at.TableHeaderInfo</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>4ec4f0187cb04f4cb6973460dfe252df</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Even though `$netver` is an array of objects, I have also tried creating new PSObjects, trying different methods to populate object properties with correct values...

```
$tableobjs = @();
foreach ($n in $netver){
$tmpname = ($n).pschildname;
$tmpver = $n.version|out-string;
$tmprel = $n.release;
$tableobjs += New-Object -Type PSObject -Prop @{
'PSChildName'='$tmpname';
'Version'='$tmpver';
'Release'='$tmprel';
}}`
```

but the values don't populate each object no matter what I have tried.  It appears to iterates through each object once (because the number of lines is the same), but the values (from `$netver`)just don't populate the objects.

```
PS C:\> $tableobjs
Version            Release               PSChildName
-------            -------               -----------
$tmpver            $tmprel               $tmpname
$tmpver            $tmprel               $tmpname
$tmpver            $tmprel               $tmpname
$tmpver            $tmprel               $tmpname
$tmpver            $tmprel               $tmpname
$tmpver            $tmprel               $tmpname
$tmpver            $tmprel               $tmpname
```

When I display them in the HTML body the values of course just display what is inside the $fragment.

Again... the question is **what am I doing wrong that is preventing the fragment from populating** with the actual values, instead of table formatting info?  I am more than willing to try suggestions, convert to other object types, or try another approach to make this happen... but obviously displaying a string in an HTML page (the only way I have seen the data in the HTML page first converting using `$netver = $netver | out-string` first) isn't a readable option.

I don't think it matters for this example, but I am using PS 3.0 at the moment.

Comment: Your problem is the final `|ft` this stringifies the output - there are no more objects which are needed for `ConvertTo-Html`. Also the `|out-string` shouldn't be neccessary.

Comment: Good point about `ft`, @LotPings, but the output objects aren't _strings_, they're_formatting objects_, and it is _their_ properties that are being used by `ConvertTo-Html`.

Comment: Thanks all!  This was really bugging me.  So basically once format table is done it is a string object, and you can’t access the properties any longer because the resulting “table” string doesn’t have them to access.  I should have taken a step back and figured it out myself, but I was stuck and appreciate the time saving point in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `|Format-Table` removed , you should get better results,
of course [mklements explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53660885/how-to-convert-powershell-object-property-values-into-an-html-table-fragment#comment94180974_53660885) is better than mine.

```
$netver = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse |
  Get-ItemProperty -name Version,Release -EA 0 |
    Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |
      Select PSChildName, Version, Release

$netverhtml = $netver| ConvertTo-Html -AS Table -Fragment -Property *

ConvertTo-HTML -body "$netverhtml" | Out-File $logfile
```